# How to compute $\lim_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{1}{h} \int_{h}^{x+h} (f(t-h)-f(t))dt?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $f \in H^1((0,\infty))$ where $H^1$ is the Sobolev space of functions $f \in L^2$ such that $f' \in L^2$ as well.

How can I compute

$$\lim_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{1}{h} \int_{h}^{x+h} (f(t-h)-f(t))dt?$$

Intuitively the answer should be

$$-\int_0^x f'(t) dt$$

but I do not know how to show it rigorously.

Comment: should there be a limit?

Comment: Hint: For every $h$, $$\frac{1}{h} \int_{h}^{x+h} (f(t-h)-f(t))dt=\frac{1}{h} \int_0^h f(t)dt-\frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt$$ Now to the limit...